# Can't get scipy.io.wavfile.read() to work

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I am trying to read a .wav file into an array so that I can then plot the array and do a FFT. I got the file open with the wave module and now I am struggling. I was advised to use scipy.io.wavfile.read(filename, mmap=False) but am not having any luck. This function should do exactly what I want it to do but it isn't. I am running Python 2.7 and maybe that is it. Please help me figure out how to make this work. The code I have written is below.

```
import scipy
import wave
harp=wave.open('/Users/williamweiss2/Desktop/Test 2/harp.wav','r')
frames_harp=harp.getnframes()
harp_rate,harp_data=scipy.io.wavfile.read(harp,mmap=False)
```

### This is the error I am getting when I try to run the program.

---> harp_rate,harp_data=scipy.io.wavfile.read(harp,mmap=False)

**AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'io'**

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have confused [SciPy's WAV module](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/io.html#module-scipy.io.wavfile) with [Python's](https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html). Remove `import wave`, use `import scipy.io.wavfile`, and call `scipy.io.wavfile.read`.

Example:

```
>>> import scipy.io.wavfile
>>> FSample, samples = scipy.io.wavfile.read('myfile.wav')
```

SciPy's module does the job of converting from a byte string to numbers for you, unlike Python's module. See the linked docs for more details.

Comment: OK. I am trying to change that right now. What are the differences?

Comment: The essential issue is that `import scipy` does *not* import all the scipy subpackages.  If you want to use `scipy.io`, you have to explicitly import it, using whatever variation of `import` that you prefer.  E.g. use `import scipy.io` and use `scipy.io.wavfile.read`, or `from scipy import io` and use `io.wavfile.read`, or `from scipy.io import wavfile` and use `wavfile.read`, etc.